# What are the MIME configuration files that point to ~/.local/share/icons?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, gnome, wine

I installed MSOffice2007 in Debian 7.2 in wine, which created its own MIME reference files in ~/.local/share/mime/ and ~/.local/share/applications.

Later I deleted wine completely and all the files in the aforementioned folders, ran

```
$ update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
```

but still there are associations in regard to icons!

*.doc files still show the MSOffice2007 icon (in Thunar, pcmanfm, Nautilus, etc) instead of the default GNOME one.

If I delete the ~/.local/share/icons folder the original system GNOME icons reappear, but if I restore the folder, the MSOffice2007 icons show up again!

So, where are the configuration files that point to ~/.local/share/icons, if not in ~/.local/share/mime and ~/.local/share/applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, finally I found the answer to this!

I quote from the [Shared MIME-info database specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/shared-mime-info-spec-0.18.html) from freedesktop.org

> "icon elements specify the icon to be used for this particular
>   mime-type, given by the name attribute. **Generally the icon used for a
>   mimetype is created based on the mime-type by mapping "/" characters
>   to "-"**, but users can override this by using the icon element to
>   customize the icon for a particular mimetype."

So the files in *~/.local/share/icons* are used as default for each MIME-type node if an **icon element** is not specified in the MIME-type .xml files. In this case, *~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/application-msword.png* was being used as the preferred icon for application/msword.png.

I hope this also helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Then remove them!

```
ls -1 --recursive ~/.local/share/mime/ | grep -E 'ms|office|word|excel|power|wine'
```

That will give you a general idea where the files are, then swing your `rm` hammer around and deal with them them.

Comment: Hey Braiam, maybe this will shook you up as much as it did to me. I Just did a test in a VM. I deleted all the files in the user folder, ALL. I did rm -Rf /home/me and then logged back again in XFCE as a user. And guess what, the MS icons still show up in thunar. WTF?

Comment: @cronilus err what? I don't see how this remove anything, in fact there shouldn't be removed anything.

Comment: @cronilus you need to update the mime tables :(. Wine doesn't have that kind of powers to affect the system directories.

Comment: I did this

# cp -R /home/me/.local/share/icons /home/root
# rm -Rf /home/me
# update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
# update-mime-database.real /usr/share/mime

Rebooted and logged in as user in XFCE.

# cp -R /home/root/icons /home/me/.local/share/icons

And the icons are still there in Thunar! So I guess there _MUST_ be some file outside the home folder that is messing up, but this is not logical and I'm not crazy.